# Protractor isDisplayed has no .catch, leading to UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: protractor

Then "Thenable" returned by `ElementFinder.isDisplayed` has no `catch`.

```
let promise = element(by.css('donut')).isDisplayed();
console.log(promise.then);  // =>  (fn, errorFn) => ...
console.log(promise.catch); // => undefined
```

If I use try-catch in an async function:

```
try {
    await e.isDisplayed(); 
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

I *do* catch the exception, but then I get an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning from Node, with a deprecation warning:

```
(node:12296) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, donut)
...
(node:12296) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How can handle that promise rejection? I can't use `.catch` on the value returned by isDisplayed, and apparently using a try-catch in an async function isn't enough.

NOTE: I'm aware that I can use `e.isPresent()` to find out in advance if `e.isDisplayed()` will throw, but the question is not how to avoid this error, but why it cannot be caught.

Comment: I've run into this same problem before. Without digging into it too much I would guess this is something that needs to be handled on the protractor side of things. It's just one of those things I've learned to use the `.isPresent()` workaround with in order to prevent the unhandled rejection error. Given the number of issues on github and the longevity of some of them I imagine it's not something that's very high on the priority list or it would have been fixed already.

Comment: @cnishina I literally said in my original post: "I'm aware I can use `e.isPresent()` "  The question is not "How can I work around this?"  The question is "Why can this error not be caught?" I'm trying to learn something about Typescript/Javascript, Promises, exception handling, etc. I find it very unnerving that there is *any* circumstance where I cannot catch an error. Telling me how I can avoid the error is *not* telling me how I can catch the error, so I won't "answer the question and use some of the info from this comment", because the comment doesn't answer the question.